# Amplitude Javascript Error t.amplitude.runQueuedFunctions is not a function

Tags: javascript, analytics, amplitude-analytics

I tried to install amplitude on my website which uses require.js. I place the Amplitude JavaScript block ad the end of my HEAD tag and it results in the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: t.amplitude.runQueuedFunctions is not a function`

Any ideas what might be causing this?